# using BIRT reports with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, reporting, flash-builder, birt

Has anyone used BIRT (eclipse.org/birt) with flex or flash builder 4 to display reports to a user?

I believe it has the ability to display reports as a web page via php or similar, so I am guessing one way to implement it would be to display the BIRT generated pages in flex inside a web control.

Wondering if anyone has done this or how you used BIRT in conjunction with your flash app?

Comment: Flex doesn't have a web control. You can use the iFrame trick; or if you're deploying to the desktop, Adobe AIR can display an HTML page. I believe AIR for Mobile supports something to display an HTML page in the app using the OSes Native browser also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had intended to do this using BIRT, and later decided to just download pdfs or xls files from the server (from BIRT).  We changed directions in our case.  (And honestly I can't recall whether BIRT even does what you're asking, but most likely it does.)

But anyway--yes, I guess you could try doing some fancy stuff to make it show up in a browser, but **is it worth it**?  You might be better off simply having excel or a pdf reader automatically open downloaded reports unless you have some especially picky requirements that you're stuck with.

That said, we found BIRT a bit of a pain to integrate.  Perhaps it was just our impatience with BIRT itself, but integration felt a bit...fragile?

We ended up using a server side Excel file lib called jxls to download files which were opened in Excel automatically. I've found that when it comes to this stuff, keeping things as simple as possible works out best. There are some little quirks of doing this straight out of Flex (such as sending parameter information with the requests), and you may need to use something like Apache Shiro for (proper) security, but it's 100% possible.

Also, don't discount reporting using Flex itself, sometimes all you need is a PrintDataGrid with some of the built-in Flex charting components.